# CSS Div Element Height Issue

Tags: html, css

I'll keep it brief. I'm trying to make a div element height 100%. All of the parent elements are set to 100% height, so that shouldn't be an issue. The original code is here: http://pastebin.com/THK13a2q

Here's a picture of the situation/problem. The dark grey background (id="content") is supposed to be 100% in height.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/poCxq.png

Comment: Depending on what you want to happen, its a matter of making that `min-height` or adding `overflow: hidden` to something.

Comment: Can you post a drawing as to what you want to achive?

Comment: Yeah, sorry the original one wasn't clear at all. Here (http://cl.ly/1i201F0A0L2s3l2m3e0e) is the kind of thing I want/need. I need the darker grey "background" div to continue down as far as the right side div does. The right side div needs to have a variable height as the content amount is variable. Therefore, so does the background.

Comment: can you post your code?
YOu don't have your block with "item 1 etc..." set to `position:absolute` do you? or anything else that would remove it from the flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has to do with the float on `#rightfeed`. You need to either set this to `clear: both` or add a div directly after it with `clear: both` applied.

If this doesn't work, please create a jsfiddle so we have something to play with.

Comment: Thanks. Your float comment got me started on the right path. One div was floated to the left and the other one to the right. When I changed the float on the right-side one AND deleted the "height: 100%" on the parent "content" div, everything fell into place. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: No problem :). If it worked, please mark it as the answer. Floats and clears are always catching me out, so I try to resist using them unless absolutely necessary, but sometimes find they're unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your css file

```
#content {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

as mikevoermans pointed out.

Comment: That simply cuts off the rest of the right side div and leaves it looking like this (http://cl.ly/2A2Q2q1Z1Z0G452o470n). I need the "content" div to continue down the page along with the right side div.

Comment: Oh I see now. Try the following also on #content.
#content {
     margin-bottom:-1000px;
     padding-bottom:1000px;
}

remove the overflow.